# C++ equivalent to Python's log library

Tags: c++, logging

With python, I can use [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) library.

What do you use for the logging library with C++?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+c%2B%2B+logging+library?

Answer (score 2):

I personally like: http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/

You have many options though.  This one is pretty similar to what you are used to.

Answer (score 2):

We are heavyweight users of [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html). I can recommend it, though I am told that the current version won't build in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: UPDATE: I have now got the log4cxx library to build in VS2010 using the vc100 compiler and it works fine in our projects. I followed the instructions here: http://www.mail-archive.com/log4cxx-user@logging.apache.org/msg03148.html .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will want to take a look at https://github.com/gabime/spdlog, they used a Python style syntax to compose log messages, and is pretty fast and safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [quill](https://github.com/odygrd/quill).
It is using a python style syntax to log and has a similar API to the python logging module. It is stable and built for low latency as well.

Comment: I narrowed my logging library down to spdlog or quill (comparing them now). I have to say that I love how clean your code in quill is. You even use BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to pick static or shared! I am liking this attention to detail!

Comment: Quill only operates with formatting done on a different thread. Feels like this could result in lost context (and the need to reproduce the bug with a debugger attached). How well does this work with sudden crashes like a segfault?

Comment: Turns out there is an answer in the wiki: https://github.com/odygrd/quill/wiki/7.-FAQ#application-crash-policy

Comment: Thanks for positive comments, trying to keep quill codebase as clean as possible:) At the moment you need to write your own signal handler to handle application crash where you call ‘quill:flush()’. The reason there isn’t one yet is because the signal handler is more specific to the application. I am planning to add one to the library in the future.